# How to mask data using python regular expression in dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I want to replace dataframe patterns using regular expressions

For example, I've following table. I want to replace account number digits with `N`, e.g. if the account is 5 numbers then it should be replaced with five N's `NNNNN`.

```
Source
Account_Num,Facility Name,Address,City
10605,SAGE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL,STATE ROUTE 264 SOUTH 191,GANADO
2425,WOODRIDGE BEHAVIORAL CENTER,600 NORTH 7TH STREET,XDSDSD
```

Target

```
Account_Num,Facility Name,Address,City
NNNNN,AAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAA,STATE ROUTE 264 SOUTH 191,GANADO
NNNN,WOODRIDGE BEHAVIORAL CENTER,600 NORTH 7TH STREET,XDSDSD
```

I was trying with following code:

```
print(df.replace(to_replace=(\[re.search(r'\\d+',str(df_str))\]),value='NNNNN', regex=True))
```

Comment: So just this `df.replace("[0-9]{5,}", "NNNNN", regex=True)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.replace` with multiple regular expression conditions:

```
df = df.astype(str).replace([r'[a-zA-Z]', '\d'], ['A', 'N'], regex=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Account_Num                Facility Name                    Address    City
0       NNNNN       AAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA  AAAAA AAAAA NNN AAAAA NNN  AAAAAA
1        NNNN  AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAA       NNN AAAAA NAA AAAAAA  AAAAAA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want whole Data frame replace digits with 'N' and words with 'A'.

Comment: How about Address column?it contains both digits and alphabets.In that case how i need to solve?

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry! I didn't notice that part :) One moment.

Comment: There we go; check now. It should work perfectly :)

Comment: it's perfectly working.Thank you soo much

Comment: hi one quick question.,can you check this code

Comment: def df_method(self,column_name):
    df[column_name]=df[column_name].astype(str).replace([r'[a-zA-Z]', '\d'], ['A', 'N'], regex=True)
    count_values=df[column_name].value_counts()
    count_values_dict=count_values.to_dict()
    return count_values_dict
df_a=df.apply(df_method)
print(df_a)

Comment: @Neeraja sure, what's the problem with it?

Comment: def df_method(self,column_name):
    df[column_name]=df[column_name].astype(str).replace([r'[a-zA-Z]', '\d'], ['A', 'N'], regex=True)
    count_values=df[column_name].value_counts()
    count_values_dict=count_values.to_dict()
    return count_values_dict
df_a=df.apply(df_method)
print(df_a)

Comment: was getting following error when. trying the above code. "TypeError: df_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column_name'"

Comment: Okay, I fixed that for you. Run this to print the new code: `print("""def df_method(df)\n    new_df = df.copy().astype(str).replace([r'[a-zA-Z]', '\d'], ['A', 'N'], regex=True)\n    count_values = new_df.value_counts()\n    count_values_dict = count_values.to_dict()\n    return count_values_dict\n\ndf_a = df.apply(df_method)\nprint(df_a)""")`